# Variable defined within function causing reference error: not defined

Tags: javascript, function, scope, web-audio-api

I'm working my way through some web audio tutorials in this O'Reilly Book: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/ch02.html#s02_2

The following code is supposed to create a system to pause an audio file and resume play.

```
// Assume context is a web audio context, buffer is a pre-loaded audio buffer.
var startOffset = 0;
var startTime = 0;

function pause() {
  source.stop();
  // Measure how much time passed since the last pause.
  startOffset += context.currentTime - startTime;
}

function play() {
  startTime = context.currentTime;
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  // Connect graph
  source.buffer = this.buffer;
  source.loop = true;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  // Start playback, but make sure we stay in bound of the buffer.
  source.start(0, startOffset % buffer.duration);
}
```

However, running the `pause()` function results in the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: source is not defined
```

Now from my point of view, this is caused because `source` has been defined with the `var` keyword making it scoped to the `play()` function and therefore inaccessible to `pause()`. Removing the `var` keyword does indeed solve the problem. Can someone just reassure me that my reasoning is correct? Is this just a typo, or is there some underlying principle that I'm not understanding? (I've checked the errata for the book and there's no mention of it there.)

Comment: You are correct.  Declare it along with your other global vars.

Comment: I'm not sure that those two code examples are really meant to be seen as part of a single real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a variable in a function makes it a local variable, i.e. it only exists in that function and thus can only be referenced in that function. Declaring it as a global variable will make it available to any Javascript function, but you generally want to pollute the global namespace as little as possible:

```
function AudioPlayer(buffer) {
  this.startOffset = 0;
  this.startTime = 0;      
  this.source = null;
  this.buffer = buffer;
}

AudioPlayer.prototype.pause = function() {
  if (!this.source) {
    return;
  }
  this.source.stop();
  // Measure how much time passed since the last pause.
  this.startOffset += context.currentTime - this.startTime;
}

AudioPlayer.prototype.play = function() {
  this.startTime = context.currentTime;
  this.source = context.createBufferSource();
  // Connect graph
  this.source.buffer = this.buffer;
  this.source.loop = true;
  this.source.connect(context.destination);
  // Start playback, but make sure we stay in bound of the buffer.
  this.source.start(0, this.startOffset % this.buffer.duration);
}
```

Which allows you to call these functions like so:

```
var player = new AudioPlayer(buffer);
player.play();
player.pause();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `source` a global variable just like `startOffset` and `startTime` are.

Comment: Also, you might need a "0" as a parameter to stop(0), at least on Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function a(advName,area) {
   onclick="sub(\'' +advName+ '\',\'' +area+ '\');"
}
```

Comment: It would be better, if you gave an intuition for the answer, along with the code.